# Generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics

Is it right that this code

```
List<Integer> test2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
test2.add(343);
int x2 = test2.get(0);
```

in compile time will be converted to this

```
List test = new ArrayList();
test.add(343);
int x = (Integer)test.get(0);
```

Something similar with autoboxing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try. Take this class with two methods that do absolutely the same thing with and without generics and autoboxing:

```
public class GenericTest{

    // use generics and auto-boxing
    // Java 1.5 or higher required
    public void generic(){
        final List<Integer> test2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        test2.add(343);
        final int x2 = test2.get(0);
    }

    // use neither generics nor auto-boxing,
    // this should be Java 1.4-compatible
    public void nonGeneric(){
        final List test2 = new ArrayList();
        test2.add(Integer.valueOf(343));
        final int x2 = ((Integer) test2.get(0)).intValue();
    }
}
```

Here's the byte code:

```
// Compiled from GenericTest.java (version 1.6 : 50.0, super bit)
public class GenericTest {

  // Method descriptor #6 ()V
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 1
  public GenericTest();
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [8]
    4  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 4]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 5] local: this index: 0 type: GenericTest

  // Method descriptor #6 ()V
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 3
  public void generic();
     0  new java.util.ArrayList [16]
     3  dup
     4  invokespecial java.util.ArrayList() [18]
     7  astore_1 [test2]
     8  aload_1 [test2]
     9  sipush 343
    12  invokestatic java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int) : java.lang.Integer [19]
    15  invokeinterface java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object) : boolean [25] [nargs: 2]
    20  pop
    21  aload_1 [test2]
    22  iconst_0
    23  invokeinterface java.util.List.get(int) : java.lang.Object [31] [nargs: 2]
    28  checkcast java.lang.Integer [20]
    31  invokevirtual java.lang.Integer.intValue() : int [35]
    34  istore_2 [x2]
    35  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 7]
        [pc: 8, line: 8]
        [pc: 21, line: 9]
        [pc: 35, line: 10]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 36] local: this index: 0 type: GenericTest
        [pc: 8, pc: 36] local: test2 index: 1 type: java.util.List
        [pc: 35, pc: 36] local: x2 index: 2 type: int
      Local variable type table:
        [pc: 8, pc: 36] local: test2 index: 1 type: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>

  // Method descriptor #6 ()V
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 3
  public void nonGeneric();
     0  new java.util.ArrayList [16]
     3  dup
     4  invokespecial java.util.ArrayList() [18]
     7  astore_1 [test2]
     8  aload_1 [test2]
     9  sipush 343
    12  invokestatic java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int) : java.lang.Integer [19]
    15  invokeinterface java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object) : boolean [25] [nargs: 2]
    20  pop
    21  aload_1 [test2]
    22  iconst_0
    23  invokeinterface java.util.List.get(int) : java.lang.Object [31] [nargs: 2]
    28  checkcast java.lang.Integer [20]
    31  invokevirtual java.lang.Integer.intValue() : int [35]
    34  istore_2 [x2]
    35  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 13]
        [pc: 8, line: 14]
        [pc: 21, line: 15]
        [pc: 35, line: 16]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 36] local: this index: 0 type: GenericTest
        [pc: 8, pc: 36] local: test2 index: 1 type: java.util.List
        [pc: 35, pc: 36] local: x2 index: 2 type: int
}
```

I don't see any obvious difference between the generic and the non-generic version, in fact here's the `diff` result for the two methods:

```
<  public void generic();
---
>   public void nonGeneric();
19,22c19,22
<         [pc: 0, line: 7]
<         [pc: 8, line: 8]
<         [pc: 21, line: 9]
<         [pc: 35, line: 10]
---
>         [pc: 0, line: 13]
>         [pc: 8, line: 14]
>         [pc: 21, line: 15]
>         [pc: 35, line: 16]
27,28d26
<       Local variable type table:
<         [pc: 8, pc: 36] local: test2 index: 1 type: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
```

As you can see, the only difference is in the line numbers and the local variable table.

Comment: Would it make a difference if this was compiled with a 1.4 compiler?

Comment: @glowcoder the first method wouldn't compile with a 1.4 compiler, and the second would be identical, that's the whole point of this type erasure crap.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, except that 
"test2.add(343);" will not change to "test.add(43);"

Comment: i copied it from scjp book, so it is matter to right them that their code is a little bit confused :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

*[[Mandatory filler to achieve > 30 chars]]*

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
List test = new ArrayList();
test.add(Integer.valueOf(343));
int x = ((Integer) test.get(0)).intValue();
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot about autoboxing